# How can I get the hexadecimal numbers from the base URL string

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am doing codes in **node js** **express js** But while working, I thought that if the **hexadecimal** number was taken from the base URL string, then my work would be easier.

**I mean:**

baseUrl: '/api/v1/movies/**61b6e1c5503b122ff9436b14**/seasons' (Get from req.baseUrl)

My base URL string is: **'/api/v1/movies/61b6e1c5503b122ff9436b14/seasons'**

I need just: **61b6e1c5503b122ff9436b14**

I am currently using the javaScript **replace()** method but it does not seem to be very effective to me. I am especially interested to know any good method.

Thanks

Comment: Please check the other two answers to the question in case you are looking for dynamic routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Regexp](https://regex101.com/r/0wcyQT/1) would be useful [unless you are looking for dynamic routes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70331485/295783)

This would get the code

```js
let baseUrl =  '/api/v1/movies/61b6e1c5503b122ff9436b14/seasons'
const hex = baseUrl.match(/movies\/(\w+)\/seasons/)[1]
console.log(hex.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are called `dynamic routes` and in express you can do like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/api/v1/movies/:hexid/seasons', (req,res) => {

   console.log(req.params.hexid);

})
```

You can find more info in their [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) ( search for `:bookId` )

Answer (score 0):

You can use `req.params` to map the route parameters in ExpressJS

```
app.get('/api/v1/movies/:hashid/seasons', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.hashid)
})
```